# How to pass helper data to all views in Laravel 5 using helper in AppServiceProvider?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to move a helper to be displayed in all views. The helper is ->

> helperFunctions::getPageInfo($cart, $total);

At this moment I have to define in every controller that information, as an example:

```
public function show($id, Request $request)
{
    $category = Category::find($id);
    if (strtoupper($request->sort) == 'NEWEST') {
        $products = $category->products()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(40);
    } elseif (strtoupper($request->sort) == 'HIGHEST') {
        $products = $category->products()->orderBy('price', 'desc')->paginate(40);
    } elseif (strtoupper($request->sort) == 'LOWEST') {
        $products = $category->products()->orderBy('price', 'asc')->paginate(40);
    } else {
        $products = $category->products()->paginate(40);
    }
    helperFunctions::getPageInfo($sections, $cart, $total);
    return view('site.category', compact('cart', 'total', 'category', 'products'));
}
```

I read and tried to move that helper to AppServiceProvider.php, inside the Boot() function.

```
public function boot()
{

    helperFunctions::getPageInfo($cart,$total);
    View::share('cart','total');
}
```

But im receiving error info:

> Undefined variable: total

-----UPDATE--------

My class helper with getPageInfo

```
class helperFunctions
{
    public static function getPageInfo(&$cart,&$total)
    {
        if (Auth::user()) {
            $cart = Auth::user()->cart;
        } else {
            $cart = new Collection;
            if (Session::has('cart')) {
                foreach (Session::get('cart') as $item) {
                    $elem = new Cart;
                    $elem->product_id = $item['product_id'];
                    $elem->amount = $item['qty'];
                    if (isset($item['options'])) {
                        $elem->options = $item['options'];
                    }
                    $cart->add($elem);
                }
            }
        }
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($cart as $item) {
            $total += $item->product->price*$item->amount;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your `getPageInfo` method. You're making a calling to the method, but where does it set the data?

Comment: @Sandeesh done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you pass the variable by reference in your helper function, you need to define them before calling. Change your view share code to this.

```
public function boot()
{
    $cart = null;
    $total = 0;

    helperFunctions::getPageInfo($cart, $total);

    $data = [
        'cart' => $cart,
        'total' => $total,
    ];

    View::share($data);
}
```

You can then access `$cart` and `$total` in all your views.

Alternatively if you want to make things cleaner, make the helper function return the array of data and pass it to the view.

Comment: thank you so much! it work perfect. I will work in the second part returning the array of data.. best regards